# How do I join on something else if nothing is found? MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Here is what I have and it does not work. It tries to join on size, if not... it join on if it's equal to `'*'`

```
INNER JOIN tbl_items ON (
  tbl_items.size = COALESCE(tbl_model.size,'*')
  AND tbl_items.type = COALESCE(tbl_model.type,'*')
  AND tbl_items.category = COALESCE(tbl_model.category,'*')
  AND tbl_items.service = tbl_testTypes.name
)
```

Comment: Your table actually includes literal `'*'`? I'm just making sure you aren't trying to specify a wildcard of some sort.

Comment: The column contains an actual '*' as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join on either the exact column match or an alternative string, you could use a pattern like

```
(tbl_items.size = tbl_model.size) OR (tbl_model.size = '*')
```

If it matches, the left side of `OR` is executed, otherwise the right side is used. Group each inside a `()`.

So fleshing out your entire `JOIN`:

```
INNER JOIN tbl_items ON (
  ((tbl_items.size = tbl_model.size) OR tbl_model.size = '*')
  AND ((tbl_items.type = tbl_model.type) OR tbl_model.type = '*')
  AND ((tbl_items.category = tbl_model.category) OR tbl_model.category = '*')
  AND (tbl_items.service = tbl_testTypes.name)
)
```